# Oracle Apex ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I tried creating a table on oracle apex but when I run it, it shows the following error: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option.
Here's my code:

```
CREATE TABLE  "PROD_INDEX" 
   (    
       "PNO" NUMBER (4,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "CATEGORY" VARCHAR(15) , 
    "PRODUCT" VARCHAR2(10), 
    "COUNTRY" VARCHAR2(9), 
    "BRAND" VARCHAR(10)), 
    "DATE" DATE, 
    "YEAR" NUMBER(4,0), 
    "COST" NUMBER(7,2), 
    "SALES" NUMBER(10,2), 
     PRIMARY KEY ("PNO") ENABLE
   )
/
```

So what could be the problem?

Comment: Your code has a typo: `"BRAND" VARCHAR(10))` . Remove the extra `(` and your statement runs. Check out the [Live SQL demo](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/fx5gda7y30vzhej9why8opxfm) .

Answer (score 1):

Run the below statement.

```
CREATE TABLE "PROD_INDEX" 
(    
    "PNO" NUMBER (4,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "CATEGORY" VARCHAR(15) , 
    "PRODUCT" VARCHAR2(10), 
    "COUNTRY" VARCHAR2(9), 
    "BRAND" VARCHAR(10), 
    "DATE" DATE, 
    "YEAR" NUMBER(4,0), 
    "COST" NUMBER(7,2), 
    "SALES" NUMBER(10,2), 
    PRIMARY KEY ("PNO") ENABLE
)
```

Comment: I did. Still no luck

Comment: Brand column closed with extra bracket

Comment: "BRAND" VARCHAR(10)),

Comment: no that's not it. the error persists despite that. but it does go away when I remove the NOT NULL ENABLE part from the second line. idk then how to specify that PNO can't be null

Comment: oh no, it's fine actually. since it's been specified as primary key it automatically is not nullable.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE  "PROD_INDEX" 
   (    
       "PNO" NUMBER (4,0),
    "CATEGORY" VARCHAR(15) , 
    "PRODUCT" VARCHAR2(10), 
    "COUNTRY" VARCHAR2(9), 
    "BRAND" VARCHAR(10)), 
    "DATE" DATE, 
    "YEAR" NUMBER(4,0), 
    "COST" NUMBER(7,2), 
    "SALES" NUMBER(10,2), 
     PRIMARY KEY ("PNO") ENABLE
   )
```

removed not null enable, and it works.

Comment: *"it works"*.  Hmmm, I find that very hard to believe, given that the actual problem is the extra bracket in the definition of the BRAND column. Here is a [Livesql demonstration](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/fx5gda7y30vzhej9why8opxfm) which shows that the extra bracket is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
CREATE TABLE  "PROD_INDEX" 
   (    
    "PNO" NUMBER (4,0) PRIMARY KEY,
    "CATEGORY" VARCHAR(15) , 
    "PRODUCT" VARCHAR2(10), 
    "COUNTRY" VARCHAR2(9), 
    "BRAND" VARCHAR(10), 
    "DATE" DATE, 
    "YEAR" NUMBER(4,0), 
    "COST" NUMBER(7,2), 
    "SALES" NUMBER(10,2)
   )
```

Also, it is considered bad practice to name your columns after Oracle reserved words (e.g. date)